# Retrieve auto saved Skype password from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: linux, skype

The email address I used to create Skype profile has been disabled and I can't get it back.

Unfortunately, I don't remember the Skype password now.
As the password is auto saved in my local machine I am able to log in to Skype account in only this particular Ubuntu[12.04 LTS] machine.

I need to retrieve the password, searched in ".Skype" directory for possible password hash but could not get any clue.

Any pointers to the required tools and methods are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Vanilla Skype Part 2](http://recon.cx/en/f/vskype-part2.pdf) [page 67], when you ask Skype to save your password, it takes a hash `md5(username\nskyper\npassword)` then it encrypts it using [AES-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) and it stores it `/home/USER/.Skype/SKYPE_USER/config.xml` (`config->Lib->Account->Credentials3`).

I have just tried to copy `config->Lib->Account->Credentials3` to a `config.xml` file on a different machine (same Skype account) and I was able to automatically login.
That can be a temporary solution while you try to solve the problem with Skype customer service.

If the password itself is of high importance to you, there are [some tools](http://lastbit.com/skype/default.asp) (commercial) that can help you brute-force it, so if your password isn't very strong there's a decent chance of recovery (since Skype is using a fast hashing algorithm, MD5).

Answer (score 1):

In a virtual machine, install Skype, make note of every file on the computer and get a checksum of the files.  Then log in with  a Skype account and save the password.  This will change or add some file on your computer.  From there you can find where Skype store their password.

An alternative option is to call customer support and see if they can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be your best bet (assuming you're more interested in getting your account back quickly, rather than hacking around):

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA109/i-ve-forgotten-my-password

> **I no longer use the email address I registered when I created my Skype account and I have never paid for any Skype product**
>
> Even if you’ve never purchased any Skype product before, we can still
>   help you register a new email address, but we first need to verify
>   your identity. Please, contact our customer service.
>
> After we verify your identity, we’ll be able to tell you what your
>   primary email address is, or change it to another one. Then you can
>   reset your password by following the instructions above.

Comment: According to that page, it already tells you that chances to get back access that way are very slim.